# Find polynomial in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Find polynomial $f(x)$ with real coefficients that satisfied:

$$x^2f(x) + 2 = f(x^2) + 2x^3$$

I find that $\deg f$ can be $1$ and $2$.

$$\deg f = n $$

$$2+n=\max(2n,3)$$

1. First case $2=n$
2. Second case $n=1$

But what next?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat : If you're going to do an edit whose only content is to fix some blatant MathJax solecisms, why do you leave equally blatant MathJax solecisms intact, such as writing $deg f$ rather than $\deg f$ (with \deg) or f(x) instead of $f(x)$, or $max(2n,3)$ instead of $\max(2n,3)$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to check if :$$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$ works (where $a$ can be $0$ when $\deg f=1$ ) . In this way you can find $a,b,c$ . Are you looking for an elegant way ?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I just corrected the equation. I am not a MathJax corrector. I only correct parts of the question when it cannot be understood well.

Answer (score 2):

Your polynomial has the form $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

Thus your equation gives
$$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+2=ax^4+bx^2+c+2x^3$$and comparing the terms of each degree on both sides yields $b=c=2$, and $a$ can be any real number.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=0$, the degree on the left is 2 and on the right is 3, so there are no solutions.

If $n = 1$, let $f(x) = ax + b$.  Solve $$x^2(ax+b) = ax^2 + b + 2x^3$$ for a and b.

If $n = 2$, let $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$.  Plug in and solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$.

If $n >= 3$, $max(2n,3) = 2n$.  Since 
$n > = 3 => n+n >= 3+n>2+n$, the degree on the right is larger than the degree on the left.  So there are no further solutions.